# How to draw picture in the text area of HTML?

Tags: html

I want to draw geometrical figure in the `<textarea>` of HTML pages, but I'm facing difficulty in how to do that. Could anyone please tell me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by "text area"? A `textarea` element? Does the figure need to be programmatically generated (circle, X pixels wide...) or can you have it as a pre-prepared JPG or GIF image?

Comment: HTML5 or Flash or a custom Java applet is what you need AFAIK.

Comment: Actually I want to draw geometrical figure with the help of drawing tools manually in the textarea of the HTML form

Answer (score 4):

You can use the HTML5 `<canvas>` element and its javascript API to draw geometric figures in an HTML document. There are many examples and tutorials of its usage, but here is one I found this morning: [Mozilla Canvas Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial)

Answer (score 2):

You can’t draw in HTML `<textarea>` elements. You can only put text in them. So the nearest you can get to drawing in them is [ASCII art](http://www.google.ae/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ascii+art).